# Azure site to use as technical repository

Tags: azure

Do we have azure based site to share technical knowledge with team. To interact with colleagues. Or Do we have ready made site which we can customize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a big assumption that I understand what your question is. Assuming you are looking for some type of collaborative website engine that can easily be deployed within Windows Azure, for the purpose of collaboration amongst your peers:

If you create a new Windows Azure Web Site and look at the gallery, you'll see several ready-made options such as Mediawiki, phpBB, DotNetNuke, Joomla, Kentico, Lemoon, mojoPortal, Orchard, Umbraco, and WordPress. I'm guessing at least one of these would help you build a collaborative knowledge site for your team.

Per your comment (which makes me think I assumed correctly): here's [starter info](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/web-sites/) on Web Sites, from the Azure portal. Also you should download the [Training Kit](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/other-resources/training-kit/), also linked from the Azure portal.

Comment: I am a week old in Azure development. Could you please provide me with some links related to this. Thanks :)

Comment: I updated my answer with links. Just start looking at the docs at [azure.com](http://www.azure.com) and you'll find a ton of stuff.